# how to avoid empty entries in sql?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE emp3(
   id int(3) auto_increment,
   first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(30), 
   email varchar(20) not null unique,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This is my table.
if i insert query like this insert into emp3   values(3,' ','',''); it is getting stored in the table.
but i should avoid this.How can i do it?

Comment: This is for which `DBMS`

Comment: You can add check constraints to throw exceptions when an invalid value is entered, or can define triggers to block such inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can add constraints according to your needs:

```
CREATE TABLE emp3(
   id int(3) auto_increment,
   first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(30), 
   email varchar(20) not null unique,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE emp3
ADD CONSTRAINT check_name_not_blank CHECK ((first_name<>'')),
ADD CONSTRAINT check_email_not_blank CHECK ((email<>''))
```

Comment: I am getting error like this.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [check_name_not_blank] CHECK (([first_name]<>'')),
CONSTRA' at line 1

Comment: It is not showing any error.but the check constraint is not working

Answer (score 0):

you yould avoid empty strings in your columns with a constraint like

```
ALTER TABLE emp3 WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_emp3] CHECK  
      (
         ([first_name]<>'') AND
         ([last_name]<>'')  AND
         ([email ]<>'')  
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this just by setting them as Not Null

```
CREATE TABLE emp3(
   id int(3) auto_increment,
   first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(30), 
   email varchar(20) not null unique,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```